# Using css on the data attribute of an <object> tag

Tags: html, css, object, styles

Is it possible to use css on a data attribute of an object tab?
I have code like this (I know I left out attributes like type):

```
<object data="www.example.com">
```

I want to know if it is possible to style "www.example.com" within my own site using css.
Because the site I am trying to style is a mobile site, it looks different in every version of any browser.  I want to style it so it looks the same across all browsers.  Is there a ramification legally to doing this to another site (not owned by me)?

Comment: When you say "style www.example.com", do you mean apply styles to the `object` element container or apply styles to whatever is hosted at www.example.com?

Comment: Confusing! What is your question exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the attribute selector.

```
object[data="www.example.com"]{
    /* styles */
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or I didn't understand anything yet.

Comment: The question is a tad ambiguous, I assume the question is asking to style the object element which satisfies the data attribute.

Comment: i am adding a mobile website to an <object> using the data attribute, in my page and with different browsers, the mobile website looks totally different/ugly.  I want to make the website www.example.com look better even though it looks different in different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot style an embedded page via the embedding page. If it were possible, it would not be legal. Neither is embedding as such legal without permission, as a rule.